# How do you define a default html in silverlight?

Tags: html, silverlight

How do you define a default html in silverlight?

In the Microsoft Development Environment, Microsoft Visual Studio, when I build a silverlight project, the code auto-generates an HTML file in the Release directory (and in the Debug directory)

Yet, I have seen some projects that have a Default.html file among the project files. And when I run the program in debug mode, the default.html comes up.

How is this done? Where is the settings which tell Visual Studio which html to use when running or debugging. In another project, when I create a project from scratch, the program runs a generated html in the debug or release directory.

How do I include my own html in a silverlight project?

Answer (score 0):

In the project settings, I found you can unselect the option to have the compiler auto-generate an html or use one that you define.